# Resolution template for Tablet App

Tags: templates, resolution

I need help with a project.
I need to create 2 templates for an aplicattion (10.1 inch tablet), but I just need to give to the developer de PSD templates of it, he will do the rest of the work (programing). So the question is, in what resolution I need to give him these templates? any "safe" area (for menu navigation)?, minimu size for buttons?any other tip? 
Thank you for your time.

Regards.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No safe area.
Buttons should be at least 44px on 44px.
Resolution is different in different devices, check this out:
http://webdev-il.blogspot.co.il/2011/03/web-design-for-mobile-screen-sizes.html

Here is a great guide for mobile design:
http://mobile.smashingmagazine.com/2012/07/12/elements-mobile-user-experience/

Good luck!

Comment: Thank you very much for your support Tomer, ill take a look!
Regards.